# Writing a debugger. How to debug a DLL accessed through LoadLibray?

Tags: debugging, winapi, assembly, breakpoints, createprocess

I wrote my own debugger using mainly `CreateProcess` and accessing the `DEBUG_EVENT` structure accordingly to load the DLLs, exceptions, threads etc setting the breakpoints (from the source code)

So far, the debugger is ok. When I set a breakpoint on a .EXE file, and also when I debug a DLL calling the host as the target for the process (similar of what IDAPro does) everything works well.

For example: the DLL contains an export called "random" with a pseudo-code like:

DLL Name: `RND.dll`:

```
Proc random::
   mov eax 1 ; (return 1) <---- I set a breakpoint here on the dll.
EndP
```

The problem is with a DLL being called from `LoadLibrary`.
For example:

**Case 1)**

---

the debugger is Ok:

The host (EXE) has this pseudo code.
EXE name: `test.exe`

```
Main:

call 'RND.Random' ; On a regular call to IAT the debug stops nicelly, since RND dll is part of the IAT table on the executable.
call 'KERNEL32.FreeLibrary' D$hLib
call 'Kernel32.ExitProcess' 0
```

---

So, when loading `RND.dll` and activating the debugger, an `OpenDialog` is opened telling the user to choose the Host (EXE) to load it. In this case `test.exe`.

So, when opening the DLL where I set a breakpoint on a "Random" export function, the debugger does correctly stop at the execution on the DLL.

But.....if my host contains the `LoadLibrary`, the breakpoint on the debugger is not being activated.
Like this:

**Case 2)**
Not working.

The EXE (host) now has this pseudo-code.
For example: `test2.exe`

```
Main:

call 'KERNEL32.LoadLibraryA' {'RND.DLL',0} | mov D$hLib eax
call 'kernel32.GetProcAddress' eax, { B$ "Random", 0}
call eax
call 'KERNEL32.FreeLibrary' D$hLib
call 'Kernel32.ExitProcess' 0
```

---

And when I open the DLL and set the breakpoint at a "random" function, the debugger is not working, since the exported function is not part of the IAT of the host.

How to attach the DLL to the host in a way that the debugger can "see" the breakpoint on the DLL function that is being called indirectly?

I tried to inject the DLL into the process, but without success.
The main function that creates the process has these settings:

```
call 'KERNEL32.CreateProcessA' DebuggeeExe,
                               CommandLineString, &NULL, &NULL, &FALSE,
                               &CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE+&NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS+&DEBUG_PROCESS+&DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS,
                               &NULL, DebuggeePath, STARTUPINFO, PROCESS_INFORMATION
```

How to fix that?
On IDAPro, it has the same functionality. I mean that I can open a DLL, set a breakpoint on an address and debug it.
But in this case, a dialog opens telling me to choose the host (EXE).

IDAPro works fine in both cases.

1. When the host (EXE) have a direct call to the DLL, meaning it is part of the IAT
2. When the host have an indirect call to the DLL that is accessed through `LoadLibrary`.

My debugger is only being able to do the first case above.
How can this be fixed?

Note: I´m used to code in assembly and this part of the code is from my assembler called `RosAsm` which I´m developing. But I´m unable to make the debugger works on those cases.
If someone can provide an example of such functionality in C using WinAPI, it would be appreciated. (Not in C++ or .Net, please, because I can read C, but I couldn´t be able to reproduce it using .Net or C++, since I can´t read it)

Many thank, in advance.

Comment: I don't understand; what does the IAT have to do with setting a breakpoint?  Typically, debuggers set breakpoints by replacing the instruction at the breakpoint with an `int 3`, are you doing something different?

Comment: This is why WaitForDebugEvent() returns LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT when a DLL gets loaded.  Lets you arm the breakpoints.

Comment: I know. It does contains all the DEBUG_EVENT structures (except RIP_INFO which is not implemented yet), but it is not finding the proper address of a library that was loaded indirectly.

Comment: About the IAT, it seems that the debugger is triggered when the module is already loaded on memory on the same process (exe). Since a executable file already contains on the IAT the necessary dlls to be used, they are loaded on the process once the executable is used. The problem relies when the module is loaded at runtime.  Adrian McCarthy make a good point, but still  the debugger is only activating the breakpoints when the modules were already being loaded and attached to the process. I´m analyzing the MS detours library and see if i can enable those cases on indirect loading a dll.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I only succeeded to make it work using the DetourCreateProcessWithDll function from MS detours library. The api seems to work fine, except it have some minor issues on the memory allocation pointers that are saved internally.
Some of the structures (DETOUR_CLR_HEADER) are being pointed incorrectly inside the function DetourUpdateProcessWithDll on the originalMicrosoft Source code.

The original source code is a mess and is a bit slow. So, i had to rewrite the whole DetourCreateProcessWithDll to try making it work on my debugger.

So far, it is working ok except a few minor problems on the synchronization of the source code and the debugged data, but this seems easier to fix.

If someone have the same problems on your own debugger that is being unable to set breakpoints directly on a DLL whose function was called by the host through Loadlibrary (or other methods), i recommend giving a try on MS Detours library.

I´m not sure yet, if i could overcome the problem on another way, but, the Detour Api seems to be working as expected.

Comment: The hooks that the Detour library creates aren't breakpoints.

Comment: The breakpoints are settled on my debugger that activated them on the source code (It works like source debugger). The problem was that when debugging a dll the breakpoints were only activated if the host (the target exe of the dll that needs to be loaded - like in ollydbg or idapro) only worked if the dll functions were called by the main host. In other words, if the IAT contained the dll that is being debugged. On the cases that the host acessd the dll from loadlibrary api (or other way of indirectly calling a dll) the debugger failed since the api was not loaded (directly) with the host.

Comment: DetourCreateProcessWithDll seems to be a good replacement of CreateProcess Api on such cases.. Btw..even OllyDbg cannot debug a DLL. It needs an app called LoadDll to make it work, and yet, you need to feed the parmeters of the exported function you are debugging. Using the Detours library, you don´t need to settle those parameters...All is needed is inject the dll on the host on a way that it looks like a part of the IAT. On this way, you can directly debug a DLL without needing to know it´s parameters or the way it is accessed from the host.

Comment: Debuggers allow setting breakpoints anywhere, not just at the entry to functions exported by DLLs.

Comment: Yes, but only when you are debugging a executable file. Ollydbg can´t debug a dll, for example. (Without the loaddll app, i mean). Another debugger that can debug a dll directly is idapro, but i was unable to understand how he allowed setting a breakpoint on a dll whose function is called indirectly from the host. For what i saw it uses Createprocess too, but i couldn´t figure it out how Idapro overcome the problem of debugging a dll that is activated through loadLibrary from the host. That´s why i gave a test on Detour Library and so far, it is working, i hope :)

Comment: You can't run or debug a DLL without some running some sort of EXE that creates the process that the DLL can be loaded into. In any case that's not what you say you're doing. You're running an EXE that uses LoadLibrary to load a DLL and hooking that DLL. You're not setting a breakpoint. Debuggers allow setting breakpoints anywhere in a DLL, even ones loaded by LoadLibrary.

Comment: Hmm...No..i said, i was running a dl hat uses a exe as it´s target (host) that loads it. For debuging a dll the debuger does this: 1) Open a dll. 2) choose a host that uses/loads it 3) start running the debugger through createprocess.  The functionality is the same as on idapro debugger (when loading/opening a dll to be debugged).

Comment: Sorry if i´m not being clear enough. English is not my native language. What the app (RosAsm) does is debugging a file (exe or a dll). When debugging a dll, a opendialog opens up saying to the user to choose the host/target executable that will load the dll onto it. The breakpoints are settled on the source code. The breakpoints are ok, when the chosen host have any direct call to the dll you opened to be debugged. But...when the host loads that dll indirectly the breakpoints were not working.

Comment: Debuggers allow debugging of an entire processes, not just an EXE or DLL, but the EXE and all of the DLLs loaded into in the process. Breakpoints are things that can be set anywhere in the EXE or anywhere in any of the DLLs. Hooking a function exported from a DLL using the IAT is only a pale imitation of a breakpoint,

Comment: Thanks...but, do you have any working example of a debugging routine that can be able to enable/disable the breakpoint when you are loading a dll that is called indirectly by the host (exe) ? I´m not being able to make the breakpoint work on such cases of indirect loading, this is why i gave a test on detours library (and worked)

Answer (score 4):

## How to set a *real* breakpoint in a DLL that was loaded with LoadLibrary

The following code shows how to set a real breakpoint using the x86 breakpoint instruction, INT 3, in a DLL that was loaded using LoadLibrary. It processes the LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT and writes the breakpoint instruction to the loaded DLL. The command takes two arguments, the name of a DLL and the name of an exported function in that DLL to set a breakpoint at the start of. The name of the DLL must include the extension but not a directory or drive letter. If the program works it will print `BREAKPOINT REACHED`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int
winperror(char const *prefix) {
    DWORD errid = GetLastError();
    PVOID *buf;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", prefix);
    if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM 
              | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS
              | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
              NULL, errid, 0, (LPTSTR) &buf, 0, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", (TCHAR *) buf);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "unknown windows error %08lx\n", errid);
    }
    return -1;
}

static int 
install_breakpoint(HANDLE process, DWORD_PTR addr) {
    static char const int3 = 0xcc;
    if (WriteProcessMemory(process, (LPVOID) addr, &int3, 1, NULL) == 0) {
        return winperror("WriteProcessMemory");
    }
    printf("breakpoint set at address %p\n", (void *) addr);
    return 0;
}

static int
install_dll_breakpoint(HANDLE process, HMODULE module,
               char const *dll, char const *function) {
    HMODULE lmodule = LoadLibrary(dll);
    if (lmodule == NULL) {
        return winperror("LoadLibrary");
    }
    void *lproc = GetProcAddress(lmodule, function);
    if (lproc == NULL) {
        return winperror("GetProcAddress");
    }
    FreeLibrary(lmodule);
    /* The debugged process might load the DLL at a different
       address than the DLL in this process, but the offset of the
       function from base of the DLL remains the same in both
       processes.
    */
    DWORD_PTR offset = (DWORD_PTR) lproc - (DWORD_PTR) lmodule;
    DWORD_PTR proc = (DWORD_PTR) module + offset;

    return install_breakpoint(process, proc);
}

static int
get_file_name_from_handle(HANDLE file, char *buf, size_t len) {
    DWORD tmp[1 + 1024 / 2];
    if (GetFileInformationByHandleEx(file, FileNameInfo,
                     tmp, sizeof tmp) == 0) {
        return winperror("GetFileInformationByHandleEx");
    }
    FILE_NAME_INFO *info = (FILE_NAME_INFO *) tmp;
    int n = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS,
                    info->FileName, info->FileNameLength / 2,
                    buf, len - 1, NULL, NULL);
    if (n == 0) {
        return winperror("WideCharToMultiByte");
    }
    buf[n] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int 
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s dll function\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    static STARTUPINFO startup;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;

    startup.cb = sizeof startup;
    startup.lpReserved = NULL;
    startup.lpDesktop = NULL;
    startup.lpTitle = NULL;
    startup.dwFlags = 0;
    startup.cbReserved2 = 0;
    startup.lpReserved2 = NULL;

    static char const rundll32[] = "rundll32";
    char buf[1024];
    if (sizeof rundll32 + 1 + strlen(argv[1]) + 1 + strlen(argv[2])
        > sizeof buf) {
        fprintf(stderr, "DLL and/or function name too long\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(buf, rundll32);
    strcat(buf, " ");
    strcat(buf, argv[1]);
    strcat(buf, ",");
    strcat(buf, argv[2]);

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, buf, NULL, NULL, TRUE,
              DEBUG_PROCESS | DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, 0, NULL, 
              &startup, &process_info) == 0) {
        winperror("CreateProcess");
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE process = process_info.hProcess;
    int first_breakpoint = 1;
    while(1) {
        DWORD continue_flag = DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED;
        DEBUG_EVENT event;

        if (WaitForDebugEvent(&event, INFINITE) == 0) {
            winperror("WaitForDebugEvent");
            return 1;
        }

        continue_flag = DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED;
        switch(event.dwDebugEventCode) {
        case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
            EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO *info = &event.u.Exception;
            EXCEPTION_RECORD *exp = &info->ExceptionRecord;
            if (exp->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT) {
                if (first_breakpoint) {
                    printf("PROCESS STARTED\n");
                    first_breakpoint = 0;
                    continue_flag = DBG_CONTINUE;
                } else {
                    printf("BREAKPOINT REACHED %p\n",
                           exp->ExceptionAddress);
                    TerminateProcess(process, 0);
                    return 0;
                }
            } 
            break;

        case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            CloseHandle(event.u.CreateProcessInfo.hFile);
            break;

        case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            printf("process exited without encoutering breakpoint"
                   " exit code = %d\n", 
                   (int) event.u.ExitProcess.dwExitCode);
            return 0;

        case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            HMODULE module = (HMODULE) event.u.LoadDll.lpBaseOfDll;
            HANDLE file = event.u.LoadDll.hFile;
            if (get_file_name_from_handle(file,
                              buf, sizeof buf) == -1) {
                return 1;
            }
            printf("LOAD_DLL   %p %s\n", module, buf);
            char *s = strrchr(buf, '\\');
            if (s == NULL) {
                s = buf;
            } else {
                s++;
            }
            if (stricmp(s, argv[1]) == 0
                && install_dll_breakpoint(process, module, argv[1],
                              argv[2]) == -1) {
                return 1;
            }
            CloseHandle(file);
            break;

        case UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            printf("UNLOAD_DLL %p\n",
                   event.u.UnloadDll.lpBaseOfDll);
            break;
        }
        if (ContinueDebugEvent(event.dwProcessId, event.dwThreadId,
                       continue_flag) == 0) {
            winperror("ContinueDebugEvent");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

To compile the program all you need to do is `cl test.c`. If you invoke it with `test d3d9.dll CreateDirect3D9` you'll see output like the following:

```
LOAD_DLL   76EE0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
UNLOAD_DLL 76AE0000
UNLOAD_DLL 766B0000
UNLOAD_DLL 76AE0000
UNLOAD_DLL 76C00000
LOAD_DLL   766B0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
LOAD_DLL   76A50000 \Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
LOAD_DLL   75DD0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll
LOAD_DLL   76890000 \Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll
LOAD_DLL   76EB0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll
LOAD_DLL   767F0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll
LOAD_DLL   75FD0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
LOAD_DLL   75D20000 \Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll
LOAD_DLL   76420000 \Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
LOAD_DLL   758B0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll
LOAD_DLL   749D0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll
LOAD_DLL   749C0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll
LOAD_DLL   767C0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\imagehlp.dll
PROCESS STARTED
LOAD_DLL   74960000 \Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll
LOAD_DLL   6E070000 \Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.dll
LOAD_DLL   74C60000 \Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll
LOAD_DLL   765E0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll
LOAD_DLL   74B00000 \Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll
LOAD_DLL   76380000 \Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll
LOAD_DLL   748B0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll
LOAD_DLL   748A0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll
LOAD_DLL   73540000 \Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv
LOAD_DLL   73510000 \Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll
LOAD_DLL   58B50000 \Windows\AppPatch\acwow64.dll
LOAD_DLL   72EC0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll
LOAD_DLL   75F60000 \Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll
LOAD_DLL   74A30000 \Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll
LOAD_DLL   6EF10000 \Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll
breakpoint set at address 6EF70A62
UNLOAD_DLL 6EF10000
LOAD_DLL   6EF10000 \Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll
breakpoint set at address 6EF70A62
UNLOAD_DLL 6EF10000
LOAD_DLL   6EF10000 \Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll
breakpoint set at address 6EF70A62
UNLOAD_DLL 6EF10000
LOAD_DLL   6EF10000 \Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll
breakpoint set at address 6EF70A62
LOAD_DLL   6FF20000 \Windows\SysWOW64\d3d8thk.dll
LOAD_DLL   736F0000 \Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll
BREAKPOINT REACHED 6EF70A62
```

The program only implements the bare minimum to demonstrate how to set a breakpoint in a DLL loaded with LoadLibrary. Notably a real debugger would need to be able to remove the breakpoint and restore the original instruction so that the program could be continued after the breakpoint is reached. Instead this program simply terminates the debugged program and exits.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ross. Indeed the problem was that the breakpoint routine i made wasn´t inside LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT The main routines to activate/deactivate the breakpoint list (and WriteProcessMem call) was outside the jmp chain of the DEBUG_EVENT structures (specially those from LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT). I did as you made on your example and it seems to working fine. I´ll make minor adjustments on the code, and test it on debugging bigger files to see it´s behavior, but so far, it is working as expected. many, many thanks :)

Comment: @guga You need to install the breakpoint in between the call to `WaitForDebugEvent` and `ContinueDebugEvent` as all the threads in the debugged process are stopped at that point. If you do that after the call to `ContinueDebugEvent` then you'll have a race condition, the threads in the debugged process will have resumed execution so its possible that the instruction you're trying to set a breakpoint on will have already been executed.

Comment: Yes, i did that way. Now the debugger is being able to debug a plugin file like the ones in Sony vegas or VirtualDub and load the dlls used from the host completely. Also, i made a routine to check either a module that is being loaded is ok or not, i mean, if one of the dlls being loaded contains no exports or no code base or can´t be loaded because it is being used by the system or the process remaps the imagebase etc, a log file, warns this conditions. Your tip/code of using the breakpoint routine inside LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT was extremely useful :)

Comment: Btw, The debugger now seems to work as expected without the problems on Idapro when facing exception outside the main code or the absence of Olly of debugging a dll only when you feed it with the parameters of the function. I made a routine to bypass to the app the exceptions whenever it can and only displays them when the dll/exe being debugged is the cause of the hang and not anyone caused by a external dll eventually loaded. More useful then having to manually fix errors on other modules as what happens on Idapro. Now the host tries to load completely regardless external exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If the user tries to set a breakpoint for a DLL that's not loaded, just make a note of it.  Later, when the debugee loads the DLL, your debugger loop gets a notification of a module load.  At that time, it can see from its notes that it has a breakpoint that needs to be set in that module, and it does the work before resuming the debuggee.

Comment: Good point. I made a check on "DEBUG_EVENT+DEBUG_EVENT.dwDebugEventCodeDis = &LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT" that contains a call to the Debugger_OnLoadDll  function.   But, after it fills all the necessary data and continues the debugging (ContinueDebugEvent). the dll is being unloaded reaching the DEBUG_EVENT+DEBUG_EVENT.dwDebugEventCodeDis = &UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT (that contains a call to the unload function).  When the exe calls the dll directly, the UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT is not activated allowing the breakpoint, but when using loadlibrary, this flag is activated somehow.

Comment: Hmm..forget the previous comment. It is unloading another dll and not rnd.dll. The module is still active, but the breakpoint is not reaching it;